# Package development: "Failed to open stream: Permission denied" when using composer dump autoload command

Tags: php, laravel, routes, package

I'm developping a package, I created all my classes and routes, but when it comes to access my routes, I keep getting the same message when trying to access them through the web :

> require(packages/uhgroup/UHTickets-laravel/src/routes/web.php): Failed
> to open stream: No such file or directory

I don't know what I did wrong...

Here are the structure of my files/folders in my project:

[image]

and my package's AppServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom("packages/uhgroup/UHTickets-laravel/src/database/migrations");
        $this->loadRoutesFrom("packages/uhgroup/UHTickets-laravel/src/routes");
    }
}
```

Moreover, when I'm running the composer dump autoload command I'm getting the following error :

> require(my_path\packages\uhgroup\Tickets-laravel\src\routes):
> Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: What is your environment (Linux, Windows)? Or is it on live server?

Comment: What's path is this `my_path\packages\uhgroup\Tickets-laravel\src\routes` and what is this `packages/uhgroup/UHTickets-laravel/src/routes`

Comment: I'm using windows but inside the project I have a Vagrant VB

Comment: but when i check the permissions all my users have all the permissions on this folder

Comment: Which permissions they have?

Comment: Total access so write read delete etc.... also for the path i wrote, it's just the path of my project inside my pc folders, and the `packages/uhgroup/UHTickets-laravel/src/routes` is my path of my package inside the laravel project. you can see on the picture above my different files in the project

Comment: It doesnt even matter where my routes are located at... I tried to put my routes outside of the project in personnal files etc etc..; but it doesn't matter... I keep having the "Permission denied" error wherever my route folder is